# Cause helper to react to event

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactive-programming

I have a template with helpers and events like:

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  edit: function () {
    console.log('helper');
    return this.value;
  }
});

Template.myTemplate.events({
  'click .edit_button': function () {
    console.log('click');
    // Toggle the value this.value
  }
});
```

Through the logs (simplified here) I can verify that the helper is called when the template is rendered on the page. However, when the event is fired the helper console message is not fired. It as though the event changing the value does not trigger processing of the helper, making the page not very reactive.

I have tried to assign a reactive variable and use it, to no avail.

```
Template.myTemplate.rendered = function () {
  this.value = new ReactiveVar();
}
// Setting and getting using the .get()/.set() methods.
```

How does one cause the helpers to be reprocessed from an event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In events you want to set value to ReactiveVar object.
In helpers you simply return that value of this object, helpers behaves like Tracker.autorun, they are reactive.

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  edit: function () {
    console.log('helper');
    // helpers are wrapped with Tracker.autorun, so any ReactiveVar.get()
    // inside this function will cause to rerun it
    return Template.instance().value.get()
  }
});

Template.myTemplate.events({
  'click .edit_button': function (e, tmpl) {
    console.log('click');

    // here you save value
    tmpl.value.set(newValue)
  }
});

Template.myTemplate.created = function () {
  this.value = new ReactiveVar();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, one thing I forgot was in the event `this` is *not* the template.